# Extracting TS interface from mongoose schema without the 'Document'?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, typescript-typings

I'm using `ts-mongoose` so I can define interfaces + schemas for my data in 1 single place. Then I'm exporting them as a mongoose schema + actual interface.

The issue I'm having is finding a simple 1 step way of extracting that interface without all the 'Document' methods & properties.

I have these two compiled together from a github issue:

```
type ExtractDoc<T> = T extends Model<infer U> ? U : never;
type ExtractI<T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof Document>>;
```

and I've been trying to write a reusable thing to combine the two:

```
export type ExtractInterface<T> = ExtractI<ExtractDoc<T>>;
```

But then when I try to use it with a Schema:

```
export type IExternalUser = ExtractInterface<ExternalUser>;
```

is throwing out: `refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.`

But if I do it with the extra 2 steps, it will work and everything is peachy.

Is there a way to extract the clean interface with just 1 call to a reusable type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to put a `<typeof>` before the `<ExternalUser>`

`export type IExternalUser = ExtractInterface<typeof ExternalUser>;`